# login_error while trying to facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook

This is first time I am trying to facebook connect (php)

While I try the method 'without javascript & xfbml' the page gets redirected to the login page of facebook,
but on typing in my credentials the page get redirected to

```
http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=<app-id>&connect=1&type=connect
```

But when I reload the page that includes the facebook sdk the session exists. Any clue whats going on ?

Comment: How about sharing your code with us?!

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a facebook setting, in particular, i believe you need to set your "site url" in core_settings / web site for your app.

I am almost certain that this has nothing to do with your actual app, rather, i think it is a facebook auth/config setting that needs to be changed because i run into this every time i clone a working app but i hastily set up the app on fb.

good luck!